# How do I create a specific key for each control on a form in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Trying to assign a key to each field in android to reference in Java.

Comment: Sorry but you have to specify your question a little bit more. I can't really understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you mean

In XML :

```
android:id="your_id"
```

and to retrieve it in your code :

```
findViewById(R.id.your_id)
```